# Porting a C code to CUDA without modifying the original code line by line

Tags: c, cuda

I am working on a project to parallelise the simulated annealing algorithm used for placement (in placement and routing) in the VPR (Versatile Place and Route) tool.

Basically, I need to convert a part of one of the many C files used by the tool to CUDA C. I just require one entire segment of the code to run on multiple cores in parallel. Each core needs to work on a separate copy of the data. So I guess I need to copy the data from host to device memory.

Is it possible to do this entire process without modifying the code line by line?

As suggest by Janisz, I am attaching the part of the code that I'm interested in.

```
while (exit_crit(t, cost, annealing_sched) == 0) 
{
//Starting here,I require this part to run on different cores. 
//Not the entire while loop.
av_cost = 0.;//These variables should be a local copy for each core.
av_bb_cost = 0.;
av_delay_cost = 0.;
av_timing_cost = 0.;
sum_of_squares = 0.;
success_sum = 0;
inner_crit_iter_count = 1;

for (inner_iter=0; inner_iter < move_lim; inner_iter++) {
//This function try_swap also has to run on different cores and also needs 
//to be run on a local copy of data, ie each core needs to completely 
//operate on its own data. And this function calls other functions which also have 
//the same requirements.
  if (try_swap(t, &cost, &bb_cost, &timing_cost, 
     rlim, pins_on_block, placer_opts.place_cost_type,
         old_region_occ_x, old_region_occ_y, placer_opts.num_regions,
         fixed_pins, placer_opts.place_algorithm, 
     placer_opts.timing_tradeoff, inverse_prev_bb_cost, 
     inverse_prev_timing_cost, &delay_cost) == 1) {
success_sum++;
av_cost += cost;
av_bb_cost += bb_cost;
av_timing_cost += timing_cost;
av_delay_cost += delay_cost;
sum_of_squares += cost * cost;
  }

#ifdef VERBOSE
      printf("t = %g  cost = %g   bb_cost = %g timing_cost = %g move = %d dmax = %g\n",
         t, cost, bb_cost, timing_cost, inner_iter, d_max);
      if (fabs(bb_cost - comp_bb_cost(CHECK, placer_opts.place_cost_type, 
                  placer_opts.num_regions)) > bb_cost * ERROR_TOL) 
exit(1);
#endif 
}

moves_since_cost_recompute += move_lim;
if (moves_since_cost_recompute > MAX_MOVES_BEFORE_RECOMPUTE) {
   new_bb_cost = recompute_bb_cost (placer_opts.place_cost_type, 
                 placer_opts.num_regions);       
   if (fabs(new_bb_cost - bb_cost) > bb_cost * ERROR_TOL) {
      printf("Error in try_place:  new_bb_cost = %g, old bb_cost = %g.\n",
          new_bb_cost, bb_cost);
      exit (1);
   }
   bb_cost = new_bb_cost;

   if (placer_opts.place_algorithm ==BOUNDING_BOX_PLACE) {
 cost = new_bb_cost;
   }
   moves_since_cost_recompute = 0;
}

tot_iter += move_lim;
success_rat = ((float) success_sum)/ move_lim;
if (success_sum == 0) {
   av_cost = cost;
   av_bb_cost = bb_cost;
   av_timing_cost = timing_cost;
   av_delay_cost = delay_cost;
}
else {
   av_cost /= success_sum;
   av_bb_cost /= success_sum;
   av_timing_cost /= success_sum;
   av_delay_cost /= success_sum;
}
std_dev = get_std_dev (success_sum, sum_of_squares, av_cost);

#ifndef SPEC
    printf("%11.5g  %10.6g %11.6g  %11.6g  %11.6g %11.6g %11.4g %9.4g %8.3g  %7.4g  %7.4g  %10d  ",t, av_cost, av_bb_cost, av_timing_cost, av_delay_cost, place_delay_value, d_max, success_rat, std_dev, rlim, crit_exponent,tot_iter);
#endif
//the while loop continues, but till here is what needs to run on different cores.
```

So to sum it up, the code given here, with the function calls it makes, has to run on many cores simultaneously, ie multiple runs of the code, each on a separate core.

Comment: simulated annealing should be a good candidate for GPU acceleration.  Other than that, as indicated by janisz, it's hard to be general.  Porting to CUDA is rarely interesting/successful unless you modify the code to expose the parallelism.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not like to change the code line by line you could try using [OpenACC](http://www.openacc-standard.org/).

OpenACC enables easily parallelizing legacy scientific and technical Fortran and C codes by compiler directives without modifying or adapting the underlying code itself. You just need to identify which areas of the code to accelerate, insert compiler directives and then the compiler does the job of mapping the original sequential computation into the parallel accelerator.

I do not have personal experience with that, but, from some Conference presentations I attended, the ease of parallelization is paid a bit with performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this useful tip. Will it also be possible to direct the compiler to assign separate memory to each thread? I need each core to work on a different copy of the data.

Answer (score 0):

> Each core needs to work on a separate copy of the data. So I guess I need to copy the data from host to device memory.

Yes, you will.  If it's a "small" matrix, it may fit in the read-only portion of your target CUDA (or OpenCL) device.  This will likely yield a significant performance benefit.  If not, your target CUDA device likely still has much faster memory accesses than your existing target.

> Is it possible to do this entire process without modifying the code line by line?

For the most part, yes.  If you take the major axis or axes of your iterative approach and instead make the body of a single loop use some clever index to load the input and/or store the results, that's where the majority of the challenge of the port lies.  It can depend on the complexity of the code being ported, but if it's a simple enough algorithm it should not be a great challenge.